# interface language selector in rails form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, internationalization, locale

What would be the way to go on having a locale selection drop down in a form?

I have a User model with a column "lng" where I store the "en","fr", etc i18n locale strings.

My goal is to have a drop down with all the languages listed " English ", " French " and on form update it stores the correct "en", "fr" value in the user table.

What would be a way to go on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the select tag http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags:

```
= form_for @user do |f|
  = f.select :lng, options_for_select([['English', 'en'], ['French', 'fr']], @user.lng)
```

I also suggest to move the array somewhere to the constant. For example, in its own method of model User. For example:

```
#models/user.rb
def self.lng_list
  [['English', 'en'], ['French', 'fr']]
end

#form
= form_for @user do |f|
  = f.select :lng, options_for_select(User.lng_list, @user.lng)
```

*edited*

In simple form you can use rails form helpers like this https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#wrapping-rails-form-helpers:

```
 = f.input :lng do
   = f.select :lng, options_for_select(User.lng_list, @user.lng)
```

Or you can use `collection` option https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections:

```
= f.input :lng, :collection => User.lng_list
```

Comment: thx a lot this works in basics, but since I'm using simple_form it doesn't display the label correctly. If I do :label => "country" its not shown and = f.label "country" does print label but not with the right css. Answer is good but maybe you know how to do this in simple form also ? thx a lot