# Rails - language selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to make an app with Rails 4. I am using simple form and bootstrap.

I am trying to ask users which language they work in.

I have an attribute in my profiles table to store the language value.

I am trying to follow this advice for making the selector: [interface language selector in rails form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862910/interface-language-selector-in-rails-form)

I am finding Simple Form anything but simple and am not having any success in following the example shown in answer to the question in the above link.

In my profile.rb, I have:

```
def.self.language_list
    [['English', 'en'], ['French', 'fr'], ['German', 'gmh'], ['Spanish', 'spa']]
  end
```

In my profile view form, I have:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
        <%= f.label  'What are your working languages?',   :class => 'question-project' %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7">
      <%= f.input :languages do %>
        <%= f.select :languages, options_for_select(Profile.language_list, @profile.languages) %> 
        <% end %> 
      </div>
    <
```

When I try this, I get an error which says:

```
NoMethodError at /profiles/2/edit
undefined method `language_list' for #<Class:0x007fe53323d078>
```

I have the same issue when I try the collection select alternative outlined in the answer to the above post.

Does anyone see what I've done wrong? Is there an easier way to put a list of languages into a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to write

```
def self.language_list
  [['English', 'en'], ['French', 'fr'], ['German', 'gmh'], ['Spanish', 'spa']]
end
```

instead

```
def.self.language_list
    [['English', 'en'], ['French', 'fr'], ['German', 'gmh'], ['Spanish', 'spa']]
  end
```

Dot between `def` and `self.language_list` is unwanted

Comment: Thanks - I should have been able to find that. Now to figure out how to display 'en' as 'English'.

Answer (score 0):

You can create
app/services/i18n_support.rb

```
class I18nSupport
  def self.locale_names
    [
      ["English", "en"],
      ["Hindi", "hi"]
    ]
  end
end
```

Now in your form you can use

`I18nSupport.locale_names`

Declaring methods globally and accessible freely is not a good practice. instead you can use class method accessible through class only